# Two select lists sharing same value binding, slow to update

Tags: knockout.js

I have two select lists bound to observable arrays containing a different sorting of the same data.  Both of these select list value binding is to the same observableArray.

**HTML**

```
  <select id="countriesAZ" data-bind="value: selectedCountry, options: countriesAZ, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Id',  optionsCaption: 'Countries a - z'"></select>

  <select id="countriesByDistance" data-bind="value: selectedCountry, options: countriesDist, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Id',  optionsCaption: 'Countries by distance'"></select>
```

**JS**

```
var myVM = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.countriesAZ = ko.observableArray([{"Id":1,"Name":"Scotland"},{"Id":2,"Name":"England"},{"Id":3,"Name":"Wales"},{"Id":4,"Name":"N. Ireland"}]);
    this.countriesDist = ko.observableArray([{"Id":1,"Name":"Scotland"},{"Id":2,"Name":"England"},{"Id":3,"Name":"Wales"},{"Id":4,"Name":"N. Ireland"}]);
    this.selectedCountry = ko.observableArray();
}

window.viewModel = new myVM();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sHatN/1/) it all seems to work well and react quickly, however, the actual array has around 1000 items and there is a delay when changing one of the selects.

I have tried to put a throttle on the value binding but didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Are you sure that it's Knockout that's the bottleneck here? It could well just be the browser rendering it. Have you profiled it using developer tools? Personally, I'd strongly advise against having 1000-long dropdown menus anyway, from a usability point of view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will run into performance problems when using large numbers of options generated by the `options` binding while also using the `value` binding. This problem is described quite well in [this blog post](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/06/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha-3-all-bindings.html) by Ryan Niemeyer. He also explains a number of ways to work around this problem.

The simplest fix, though, might be to use my [Freedom plugin](https://github.com/mbest/knockout-freedom) that fixes the underlying Knockout bug. Here's your example with the Freedom plugin included: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/sHatN/3/

Comment: Thanks for this.  I had looked on ryans site first but didn't find that.